# Check if user with ID or name X is online

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to check if a user with a certain id or name is online in Wordpress?

Answer (score 3):

I think the function you want is `is_user_logged_in`. Maybe try

```
wp_set_current_user($id, $name = '')
```

To set the current user by id, and then check if they are logged in using

```
is_user_logged_in()
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: slight problem with this approach, you have changed the global variable $current_user value by passing in a new user. After checking that if that user is online you need to switch it back to what it was before. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

jkeesh has a good solution, but that may not offer live information. `is_user_logged_in()` is a conditional statement for performing actions.

It's helpful if you want to do this for example:

When logged in, show `smiley.jpg`

When logged out, don't show `smiley.jpg`

If you are simply trying to do one of those features which forums have that show "x number of users online" and list their usernames, I don't believe this conditional statement can do that. That would either require some custom code or another plugin.